# I am using csharp to get an access token from Autorization code

Tags: c#

I am using universe.com API https://developers.universe.com

when I run the below code I am getting 401, unauthorized access.

```
 public static string GetAccessToken(string clientId, string secret, string AUTHORIZATION_CODE, string redirect_uri)
        {
            var uri = string.Format("https://www.universe.com/oauth/token?grant_type=authorization_code&client_id={0}&client_secret={1}&code={2}&redirect_uri={3}", clientId, secret, AUTHORIZATION_CODE, redirect_uri);
            var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
            webRequest.Method = "POST";
            webRequest.Accept = "application/json";
            webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var result = reader.ReadToEnd();

                //var credentials = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Credentials>(result);

                //return credentials.accessToken;
                return result.ToString();

            }
        }
```

Here are my test application details:

Application Id:
4eae99d7317bf63ba9204accbb76635d528b6a12559464ed1789ef3e5e6ca2f2
Secret:
04cecca5a04d31e17cd29979de2da585bfd7ce2e2036c41f276131dfbd2d2ef2
Autorization code :  2477b8473fa06b4816fd33e91d782d2e388642539a4e31ce9560b65d28e7fcff 
redirect URI(local host) : urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob

string clientId = "4eae99d7317bf63ba9204accbb76635d528b6a12559464ed1789ef3e5e6ca2f2";
            string secret = "04cecca5a04d31e17cd29979de2da585bfd7ce2e2036c41f276131dfbd2d2ef2";
            string AUTHORIZATION_CODE = "2477b8473fa06b4816fd33e91d782d2e388642539a4e31ce9560b65d28e7fcff";
            string redirect_uri = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob";
           string token = GetAccessToken(clientId, secret, AUTHORIZATION_CODE, redirect_uri);

```
        Console.WriteLine(token.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public async Task<string> GetAccessToken(string clientId, string redirectUri,string clientSecret, string authCode, string grantType)
        {

            var testData = new Data(){ClientId = clientId,
                ClientSecret = clientSecret,              
             RedirectUri = redirectUri,
             GrantType = grantType,
             Code = authCode
            };

            var uri = 
                $"https://www.universe.com/oauth/token";
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
                var str = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(testData);
                var dataContent = new StringContent(str);
                var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(uri, dataContent);
                return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }

        }
        public class Data
        {
            [JsonProperty("code")]
            public string Code { get; set; }
            [JsonProperty("grant_type")]
            public string GrantType { get; set; }
            [JsonProperty("client_id")]
            public string ClientId { get; set; }
            [JsonProperty("client_secret")]
            public string ClientSecret { get; set; }
            [JsonProperty("redirect_uri")]
            public string RedirectUri { get; set; }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you. how do I integrate it in to my existing code mentioned above please?

Comment: First of all, tell me please, why do you use POST when your request is GET? I think if you will replace POST on GET it maybe will help you. If won't i'll write code using httpclient

Comment: If you look at the documentation Accessing token uses POST  on their guide https://developers.universe.com/v2/reference

Comment: Sorry, now i see it. Did you try demo with your values?

Comment: Where do I do that?

Comment: About try demo, you can do it filling fields under each method of documentation and press 'Try it' at the right of that method in documentation. Did you try  my edited code?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should pass the request parameters in body ( don't embed them in the URL )

```
public static string GetAccessToken(string clientId, string secret, string AUTHORIZATION_CODE, string redirect_uri)
{
  try
  {
    HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://www.universe.com/oauth/token");
    webRequest.Method = "POST";
    webRequest.Accept = "application/json";
    webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
    byte[] buffer = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string.Format("grant_type=authorization_code&client_id={0}&client_secret={1}&code={2}&redirect_uri={3}", clientId, secret, AUTHORIZATION_CODE, redirect_uri));
    webRequest.ContentLength = buffer.Length;
    using (var reqStrm = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
    {
     reqStrm.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    }

    using (HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse())
    {
        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream()))
        {
         return reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }

  }
  catch (Exception ex){return ex.Message;}
}
```

Maybe you will still get the error, because the documentation [here](https://developers.universe.com/v2/docs/authorizing-with-oauth) says

redirect_uri: REDIRECT_URI – The URL must match exactly the redirect_uri passed to /authorize, That means you should first call /authorize. You should also use the same CookieContainer for both of requests.
I also recommend you add UserAgent header to your request